# can't start couchbase server 2.2.0 in non-root sudo

Tags: linux, couchbase, linux-mint

I an trying to install couchbase server 2.0.2 from http://www.couchbase.com/communities/python/getting-started

I have  Linux mint 15.

I went to "Installing on Ubuntu as Non-Root, Non-Sudo"

I successfully executed:

```
dpkg-deb -x couchbase-server-enterprise_2.2.0_x86_64.deb $HOME

./bin/install/reloc.sh
pwd
```

When I tried `./bin/couchbase-server -- -noinput -detached I got the following output:

```
 ./bin/couchbase-server -- -noinput -detached
```

The maximum number of open files for the couchbase user is set too low.
It must be at least 10240. Normally this can be increased by adding
the following lines to /etc/security/limits.conf:

couchbase              soft    nofile                  
couchbase              hard    nofile

Where  is greater than 10240.

mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/opt/couchbase’: Permission denied
./bin/couchbase-server: 71: cd: can't cd to /opt/couchbase/var/lib/couchbase

What am I doing wrong?

thanks in advance

Comment: What is the result if you run sudo service couchbase status?

Comment: I appreciate your assistance ... I am new to couchbase ...

Comment: What is the actual command? I have opt/couchbase installed in my home directory

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I installed couchbase on linux mint 13 (A virtual machine).

Visit here to pick your flavour, 64/32bit, distro, enterprise or community http://www.couchbase.com/download

Right clink on the package you want and copy the link address and then add to the commands below. (I included the version I downloaded)

1. sudo wget http://packages.couchbase.com/releases/2.2.0/couchbase-server-enterprise_2.2.0_x86_64.deb
2. sudo dpkg -i couchbase-server-enterprise_2.2.0_x86_64.deb
3. sudo service couchbase-server status

During instalation you might find you are missing the libssl library, if you are it'll tell you and you can just sudo apt-get install LIB_SSL_VERSION

Comment: avengedsixfold; that did the trick! I was hoping to get it installed locally but I am grateful for getting it started. Now to struggle with Python SDK! I may be back for more good advice! Thanks again, Chris

Comment: Happy to help! If this has resolved your problems so far then you can set this answer to accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Run

```
./bin/install/reloc.sh `pwd`
```

instead of

```
./bin/install/reloc.sh
pwd
```

Answer (score 0):

I thought Chris was asking about non-root, no sudo...  I was interested in doing the same for development on an Ubuntu 14.04 vbox and ran into this issue.

- You can get your current hard limit with (I got 4096):

  `$ ulimit -Hn`
- Edit /etc/security/limits.conf (domain is a user or group)

  `<domain>      <type>   <item>         <value>`
- Edit the /etc/pam.d/common-session and insert at the bottom:

  `session required pam_limits.so`

This should answer the mail, but you probably want to implement a script that runs this per process since this is a permanent solution. Looking forward to feedback on this if anyone has any.

- Standing on the shoulders of giants...

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-couchbase-from-source-with-git-and-make-on-a-debian-7-vps

https://github.com/couchbase/sync_gateway/issues/218

https://askubuntu.com/questions/162229/how-do-i-increase-the-open-files-limit-for-a-non-root-user

Hope that helps.

Cheers!